# Algorithm to find a number to divide by

Tags: algorithms

I have a following problem.

I have a variable `$x$`, I have a target value `$y = 20$` and I have a `$z$` - 'divisor/multiplier range' of $0$ to $+5$ with $1$ digit precision.

What I need is I need to find a multiplier/divisor that will make `$x$` as close as possible to `$y$`.

So an example would be `$x=5$`. Obviously `$z=4$` but how does computer arrive at that$?$

One simple thing that comes to mind is something like this:

```
z=0;
while (n < 20) {
  if (z==5) {
      break;
  }
  z = z + 0.1;
  n = x*z; 
}
```

This will return maximum `$z$` for which $n<20$ so the result will be 'close enough' I guess. However that seems to be vastly inefficient for case when $x$ is small, hence my question on how to make it work...

EDIT: Oh and I forgot that $x$ can be greater than $20$, so then it has to divide by something between $0.1$ and $5$... so it gets even more complicated...

EDIT2: I realize that it looks ridiculous = simple answer would be get `$y$`, divide by $`x`$ and you get your `$z$`. However, the problem is that this example is a simplification for a problem that I am facing - I do not control the `$n=x\times z$` part - this is done by a black box thing that has some obscure algorithms inside so all I can do is give it a number and see a result. And I would like to arrive at a closest match with as few iterations as possible.